# How to create a semi circular gauge using high chart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have to create a semi circular gauge chart using high chart. I have got [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/EjRLw/280), but this one has a full circular dial. What is required is a semicircular dial, i.e., containing only the upper part of dial.

Answer (score 2):

You can add center parameter to pane section,

```
pane : {
  center: ['50%', '100%']
   ...
}
```

See the modified demo, http://jsfiddle.net/EjRLw/524/

Refer to API at High chart http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#pane.center

Answer (score 1):

```
    pane: {
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 90,
        background:[]
    },
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the last function like this and you will have upper part of the full dial

```
 // Add some life
    function(chart) {
        setInterval(function() {
            var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
                newVal, inc = 100;

            newVal = inc;
            if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 100) {
                newVal = 50;
            }

            point.update(newVal);

        }, 3000);

    });
```

Comment: I do not think this is what he is asking for. That just moves the needle to the '100' point. The gauge is still a "full circle" with the actual charting area a half circle and black space on the bottom.

Comment: Check this            plotBands: [{
                from: 0,
                to: 100,
                innerRadius: '40%',
                outerRadius: '65%',
                color: {linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 1 },
                    stops: [
                        [0, '#fff'],
                        [1, '#fff']
                    ]} // green
            }, {
                from: 0,
                to: 100,
                innerRadius: '45%',
                outerRadius: '60%',
                color: '#000' // red
            }]
one change made `to:100`. this one you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background shape to arc e.g.

```
pane:{
      background:{
        ...
        shape:'arc'
        ...
      }
    }
```

Then use this CSS to remove space below the semicircle

```
.chatcontainer > div {
   margin-bottom: -35% !important
}
.chatcontainer > div.highcharts-container > svg {
   margin-bottom: -35%; max-height: 65% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                Highcharts.chart('SemiCircularGauge', {
                    chart: {
                        type: 'gauge',
                        backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8',
                        plotBackgroundColor: {
                            stops: [
                                [0, '#FFF4C6'],
                                [50, '#FFFFFF'],
                                [100, '#FFF4C6']
                            ]
                        },
                        height: 250
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Semi Circular Gauge',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                    },
                    pane: [{
                        startAngle: -90,
                        endAngle: 90,
                        background: null,
                        center: ['50%', '100%'],
                        size: 300
                    }, {
                        startAngle: -90,
                        endAngle: 90,
                        background: null,
                        center: ['50%', '100%'],
                        size: 50
                    }],
                    exporting: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    yAxis: [{
                        min: 0,
                        max: 100,
                        minorTickPosition: 'outside',
                        tickPosition: 'outside',
                        labels: {
                            rotation: 'auto',
                            distance: 20
                        },
                        plotBands: [{
                            from: 0,
                            to: 20,
                            color: "#A45D5B" 
                            }, {
                            from: 20,
                            to: 40,
                            color: "#C7A46F" 
                            }, {
                            from: 40,
                            to: 60,
                            color: "#D0BF94" 
                            }, {
                            from: 60,
                            to: 80,
                            color: "#71AA8D" 
                            }, {
                            from: 80,
                            to: 100,
                            color: "#3E7873" 
                            }],
                        //pane: 0,
                        title: {
                            text: '<span style="font-size:8px">Semi Circular Gauge</span>',
                            y: -20
                        }
                    }, {
                        min: 0,
                        max: 100,
                        minorTickPosition: 'outside',
                        tickPosition: 'outside',
                        labels: {
                            rotation: 'auto',
                            distance: 20
                        },
                        plotBands: [{
                            from: 0,
                            to: 20,
                            innerRadius: '100%',
                            outerRadius: '105%',
                            color: "#A45D5B" 
                            }, {
                            from: 20,
                            to: 40,
                            innerRadius: '100%',
                            outerRadius: '105%',
                            color: "#C7A46F" 
                            }, {
                            from: 40,
                            to: 60,
                            innerRadius: '100%',
                            outerRadius: '105%',
                            color: "#D0BF94" 
                            }, {
                            from: 60,
                            to: 80,
                            innerRadius: '100%',
                            outerRadius: '105%',
                            color: "#71AA8D" 
                            }, {
                            from: 80,
                            to: 100,
                            innerRadius: '100%',
                            outerRadius: '105%',
                            color: "#3E7873" 
                            }],
                        pane: 1,
                        title: {
                            text: ''
                        }
                    }],
                    plotOptions: {
                        gauge: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: false
                            },
                            dial: {
                                radius: '100%'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Semi Circular Gauge',
                       data: [68],
                        yAxis: 0
                    }, {
                        name: 'Semi Circular Gauge',
                        data: [68],
                        yAxis: 1
                    }]
                },
                    function (chart) {
                        if (!chart.renderer.forExport) {
                            setInterval(function () {
                                var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
                                    newVal,
                                    inc = 0;
                                newVal = point.y + inc;
                                if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 100) {
                                    newVal = point.y - inc;
                                }
                                point.update(newVal);
                            }, 3000);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: To test it : http://jsfiddle.net/cb4kfsjg/