# HighCharts Semi Circle dial that positions correctly

Tags: highcharts, gauge

While I have found this post that advises how to change the gauge chart to a semi circle...

[How to create a semi circular gauge using high chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142820/how-to-create-a-semi-circular-gauge-using-high-chart)

It's a bit of a faulty design as all we do is shift the chart down ward. This leaves a bunch of white space...

Does anyone know how to do this, while keeping the dial chart centered?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can play a little with `width:` and `height:` of the container and with pane `size:`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/EjRLw/631/